# Write.csv Error: Writes .csv file with parameter names (header) and no data)

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to write a csv with my results from a dredge (in MuMin) based on an occupancy model from Rmark.

```
BEAR.models=mark(BEAR, model="Occupancy", model.parameters=list(p=list(formula=~Trail+DetectionDist+WeekDay),Psi=list(formula=~Zone*Phase)), groups=c("Zone", "Phase"))
MuMIn:::fixCoefNames(names(coeffs(BEAR.models)))
sqddp=dredge(BEAR.models, fixed=c("psi(Zone),psi(Phase)"),rank=QAIC, chat=2.2392474) 
write.csv(sqddp,file="PAllBearQaic.csv")
```

and the result:

```
> write.csv(sqddp,file="PAllBearQaic.csv")
Error in subset_model_selection(NextMethod("[<-"), attributes(x), if     (is.character(j)) j else colnames(x)[j]) : 
  argument "j" is missing, with no default
> read.csv("PAllBearQaic.csv")
 [1] X                p..Intercept..   p.DetectionDist. p.Trail.             p.WeekDay.       Psi..Intercept.. Psi.Phase.       Psi.Zone.        Psi.Phase.Zone.  df               logLik           QAIC             delta            weight          
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

The .csv exists but there is no data, only the header. However, when I just type "sqddp" in R, it returns data so the original function is working. How can I supply "argument j", or otherwise get the data into the .csv?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the class of `sqddp`? Is it a dataframe or something else?

Comment: I asked str(sqddp) and this is the first line: 
    Classes ‘model.selection’ and 'data.frame':     40 obs. of  13 variables:

Comment: Is sqddp just a dataframe, or is it an object containing a dataframe (seems like it). If so, you need to write the dataframe to file, not the entire object.

Comment: Thanks Heroka. How can I reference the dataframe only?

Comment: by it's name (you can see that by doing names(sqddp) or str(sqddp) and then you can do sqddp$name_of_data